# How to write byte string to a file in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, encoding

I need to convert a string into base16-be format. For this I used the iconv module as below:

```
var Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer;
var Iconv  = require('iconv').Iconv;
var iconv = new Iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-16BE');
var str = 'Hello \'s world';
var con = iconv.convert(new Buffer(str));
console.log(con);
```

The output is:

```
`<Buffer 00 48 00 65 00 6c 00 6c 00 6f 00 20 00 27 00 73 00 20 00 77 00 6f 00 72 00 6c 00 64>`
```

Now I want to write the following representation of this in a file:

```
00480065006c006c006f00200027007300200077006f0072006c0064
```

which I will read and pass to a URL.

Using 'fs', if I try to write in a file, it  stores the original string instead of this. Can someone please guide me what is the proper way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the Buffer value with the `buffer.values()` method which returns an iterator.

```
var result = ""

for (var value of buffer.values()) {
  var hex = value.toString(16)
  result += hex.length == 2 ? hex : "0" + hex
}
```

This should take a buffer as input and return in the result variable a string containing the representation you want.

Comment: Thanks for giving the hints. I was doing somewhat the same but was not knowing the proper way. Thanks again.